# jqChart: starting with disabled serie

Tags: php, jqchart

I have a php page that use jqChart PHP.

It shows 4 lines, and here a piece of code.
It there a way to start the graph with 2 of the lines "disabled" so not visible on the chart?

```
->addSeries('Budget C.F.', "SELECT valoreBudget FROM graph WHERE anno_corrente = 0 and tipo_grafico = 'CFBUDGET' ORDER BY annomese")
->addSeries('Previsione C.V. - Nappo', "SELECT valoreBudget FROM graph WHERE anno_corrente = 0 and tipo_grafico = 'CVNAPPO' ORDER BY annomese")
    ->addSeries('Costi Totali previsti', "SELECT g1.valoreBudget + g2.valoreBudget as ricavo FROM graph as g1 JOIN graph as g2 ON g1.annomese = g2.annomese AND g1.anno_corrente = g2.anno_corrente
                WHERE g1.anno_corrente = 0 and g1.tipo_grafico = 'CFBUDGET' AND g2.tipo_grafico = 'CVNAPPO' ORDER BY g1.annomese")
->addSeries('da Business C.F. + C.V.', "SELECT valoreBSN FROM graph WHERE anno_corrente = 0 and tipo_grafico = 'CBSN' ORDER BY annomese")

    ->setSeriesOption('da Business C.F. + C.V.',array(
    "type"=>"line",  
))
->setSeriesOption('Budget C.F.',array(
    "type"=>"line",
))
->setSeriesOption('Previsione C.V. - Nappo',array(
    "type"=>"line",
))
->setSeriesOption('Costi Totali previsti',array(
    //"type"=>"area",
    "type"=>"line",
))
```

I hope it is possible adding some more options in setSeriesOption, but I was not able to discover how.

Thanks in advance
Matt